# Return Dataset as Excel

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

New to MVC and having some trouble with what should be simple.  I'm trying to return a dataset to just an Excel spreadsheet without any real UI.

Here's my code (cannibalized from a few sources):

Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult GetCommissionsExcel(string agencyid, string month, string year)
    {
        try
        {
            var as400rep = new iSeriesRepository(new iSeriesContext());
            var results = as400rep.GetCommissionExcel(agencyid, month, year);

            string xml = String.Empty;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(results.GetType());

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, results);
                xmlStream.Position = 0;
                xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
                xml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
            }

            var fName = string.Format("CommissionsExcelExport-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));

            byte[] fileContents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fName);

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The jQuery call:

```
function getExcelExport() {
    var activePane = $('div.tab-pane.active');

    var agencyCompany = $(activePane).find('#Agency_AgencyId').val();
    var month = $(activePane).find('#CommissionMonth').val();
    var year = $(activePane).find('#CommissionYear').val();

    var url = '@Url.Content("~")' + 'AgencyManagement/GetCommissionsExcel';

    window.location = 'AgencyManagement/GetCommissionsExcel';

    //$.post('@Url.Action("GetCommissionsExcel", "AgencyManagement")' , {agencyid: agencyCompany, month: month, year: year});
};
```

It pulls back the data, but I can't figure out how to get it to pop from the search window.  It looks like the window.location line makes the call, but I need to post the parameters to the call and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Just needed to call the jQuery as follows:

```
window.location = 'AgencyManagement/GetCommissionsExcel?agencyID=' + agencyCompany + '&month=' + month + '&year=' + year;
```

And I needed to append ".xls" to the filename in the controller action.

```
var fName = string.Format("CommissionsExcelExport-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
            fName = fName + ".xls";
```

Worked like a charm